# iOS: How to prevent location-related alerts from appearing when in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, alert, core-location

My iOS app uses location services in the background when in a certain mode of operation. It works fairly well, managing to stop processing if the user disables LocationServices in Settings/Privacy - either globally or for my app only - while it is in the background.

When the user disables location services for my app only, all goes fine. When the user disables location services globally, however, I'm not able to prevent the standard alert saying 'Turn on Location Services to Allow "MyApp" to Determine your Location' from appearing (I mean, the alert shows almost immediately while I am in the Settings app, not when I come back to my app resuming it to the foreground).

I seem to understand that other location-based apps are able to avoid this: for example, MotionX-GPS does not cause any alert to appear when recording a track in the background, even if the user disables global location services in Settings. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Wolf

Answer (score 0):

`<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`'s `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` looks promising. You could implement that method in your CLLocationManager delegate, and shut yourself down depending on the new `CLAuthorizationStatus` value.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Hal! Yes, I'm implementing that method in my delegate, but when it is called the alert 'Turn on Location Services...' is already on screen.